# Are wireless card interchangeable? can I mount a BCM4313 on a notebook that originally mounted a rt3290?

Tags: wireless, hardware

I would like to mount a wireless card (BCM4313) on a notebook that used to mount a rt3290 card, is it possible? Will it work?

Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, you can. In some cases, the manufacturer of the laptop enforces, in the BIOS, what is known as a whitelist. That means the computer will boot *only* if the wireless card is on the approved list. You can find more information here, for Lenovo laptops, as an example: http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Problem_with_unauthorized_MiniPCI_network_card

You can also Google your laptop manufacturer and 'whitelist.'

Comment: I actually encoutered this problem on the hp notebook from witch I took the BCM4313 and mounted on it the rt3290.
I heard there are ways to install modified BIOS that ignore the whitelist, but I'm afraid to brick the notebook.
I think I'm gonna buy a compatible wireless card to mount on this second notebook.

Comment: May I assume you've exhausted all efforts to get the rt3290 going?

Comment: absolutely yes :(

Comment: Please see your other question.